# I Need Help Solving A Riddle - Its Just An Image?

Tags: visual, cipher

So I was in this [hackathon competition](https://repl.it/jam) where they promised the people who placed in the top 3 a lot of money and then they delayed the results two weeks. Yesterday, when they were supposed to announce the release of the results, they were radio silent on the issue. But, in their newsletter they left a riddle - just this image. Maybe it has the results? Could anyone help me solve this thing?

[image: Image Here]

Comment: Not sure if this is important, but looks a bit like [Wall E](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/c2/WALL-Eposter.jpg) robot.

Comment: Wild guess: Have you tried running it through Piet?

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath within the meaning of our contest policy, this is not a contest. It is acceptable here. Unless you can point at something that specifically forbids sharing that type of item from the newsletter with outsiders or asking for help with it, there’s no reason for us to prevent it being posted here. Whether it’s sporting of someone to (specifically) ask for help as happened here, vs. asking for a solution, is maybe debatable, but that’s not a hair I’m going to split.